# Included base package ID 16 already in use

Tags: android, build, package, android-gradle-plugin

My project was able to build fine. Then I was trying to include an external project into my project. After struggling to include the project, I stopped and decided I don't need the external project. I tried rebuilding my existing project and this is the error I'm getting now. My suspicion is that something is misconfigured in Android Studio while I was trying to include the external project. Any ideas what this error means?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':project:processReleaseResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar -M /Users/jitse/workspace/AndroidStudioProjects/project/build/bundles/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/jitse/workspace/AndroidStudioProjects/project/build/res/all/release -A /Users/jitse/workspace/AndroidStudioProjects/project/build/bundles/release/assets -m -J /Users/jitse/workspace/AndroidStudioProjects/project/build/source/r/release --non-constant-id --output-text-symbols /Users/jitse/workspace/AndroidStudioProjects/project/build/bundles/release
>     Error Code:
>       1
>     Output:
>       Included base package ID 16 already in use!

Comment: I have the same error, and I'm also unsure of how it came up. I'm using build tools 19.1, but other than that the same setup. I added a new source library project, and this error popped up.